# Strange Device Properties of C1060 GPU

Tags: c++, cuda, nvidia

I am running a bit of code that simply gets information about the GPU and prints it out. However, I am getting very strange (and changing) numbers. The code is simply a bunch of `cudaDeviceProperties` prints.

Output:

```
Global memory:   0mb
Shared memory:   136723055446kb
Constant memory: 136723055540kb
Block registers: 1359818672
Warp size:         32597
Threads per block: 1359826784
Max block dimensions: [ 32597, 1357152712, 32597 ]
Max grid dimensions:  [ 1359925824, 32597, -1220823104 ]
```

None of these numbers make any sense, which leads me to think there may be something wrong with the card/drivers/OS.

Nvidia-SMI: 340.93.
OS: Ubuntu 14.04.

Any help would be appreciated into what could possibly be going on here.

```
cudaDeviceProp props;
cudaGetDeviceProperties(&props, i);
cout << i << ": " << props.name << ": " << props.major << "." << props.minor << endl;
cout << "  Global memory:   " << props.totalGlobalMem / mb << "mb" << endl;
cout << "  Shared memory:   " << props.sharedMemPerBlock / kb << "kb" << endl;
cout << "  Constant memory: " << props.totalConstMem / kb << "kb" << endl;
cout << "  Block registers: " << props.regsPerBlock << endl << endl;

cout << "  Warp size:         " << props.warpSize << endl;
cout << "  Threads per block: " << props.maxThreadsPerBlock << endl;
cout << "  Max block dimensions: [ " << props.maxThreadsDim[0] << ", " << props.maxThreadsDim[1]  << ", " << props.maxThreadsDim[2] << " ]" << endl;
cout << "  Max grid dimensions:  [ " << props.maxGridSize[0] << ", " << props.maxGridSize[1]  << ", " << props.maxGridSize[2] << " ]" << endl;
cout << endl;
```

Comment: Which CUDA version are you using? Also, please show the code you are using.

Comment: Could you please provide the code so we diagnose the problem?

Comment: study the deviceQuery [cuda sample code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#device-query) to learn how to use the API correctly.

Comment: I desperately tried adding the code, but the editor was convinced that something was not in code brackets. I will try to post the code again, as well as the output from nvidia-smi (which is perfectly normal, as far as I can tell).

Comment: What status does the `cudaGetDeviceProperties` call return? It's quite possible you are just looking at the contents of uninitialised memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, the problem happened to be code generation. The C1060 is an old gpu with compute capability. 1.3. CUDA 6.5 by default (probably) generates code for newer architectures, but the problem was solved by explicitly stating `--gpu-arch=compute_13` while compiling with nvcc. Hope this helps anyone who's faced this.